# Zabbix Calculated Item Trouble

Tags: ubuntu, window, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, zabbix

Big Zabbix fan here, new to the details.

I have a script that runs on my Remote Desktop server, it writes to a file with the current TS sessions.

Zabbix in turn reads this file, 2 different ways;

1, `vfs.file.contents[C:\scripts\users\count.txt,ascii]`

2, `log["C:\scripts\users\count.txt","([0-9]+)",ascii,,,\1]`

Both of these methods work flawlessly, they read the number and present it within Zabbix.

However, I am unable to graph of either of these items, it only presents as history.

I have read that if I can calculate my item, I can then get a graph going.

I have been breaking my eyes over google and zabbix docs for hours and cannot get a calculated item too work.

What I have is this;

```
last("log["C:\scripts\users\count.txt","([0-9]+)",ascii,,,\1]")
```

I would assume that the this would run the bracketed calculation and retrieve the 'last' number. However nothing happens.﻿ I am missing something, but I don't know what.

All I want is a graph showing connected RDP sessions using the numbers from my working items but so far it seems out of reach.

Answer (score 1):

If this is Zabbix 3.0, you should be able to set log item to numeric and graph it directly - see this [what's new entry](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/introduction/whatsnew300#graphing_log_items).

If it's an older version of Zabbix, you should be able to set `vfs.file.contents` item to numeric straight away and just graph it. Even if it is Zabbix 3.0, it might make sense to use `vfs.file.contents` instead of the `log[]` item - `log[]` item is meant to read a file that is appended, but you are replacing file contents.

Note that in both of these items you don't have to specify `ascii` - the file would be perfectly read with the default of `utf8`. And in the log item the value extraction (number regexp and the `\1` parameter) is redundant as well, as your file contains a number only.

And last, to answer your original question (although you should not use this method), your calculated item is missing proper quote escaping. Something like this might work:

```
last("log[\"C:\scripts\users\count.txt\",\"([0-9]+)\",ascii,,,\1]")
```

What you say about nothing happening is a bit doubtful - most likely, the calculated item had an error listed next to it in the config section.

But again, most likely you want to use a plain `vfs.file.contents` item, set to numeric values.